# como validar los que no tenga datos vacios en Formulario de Android Studio

Tags: android-sqlite

Este es el código:

```
AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper
                        (Alta_Alumno.this, "administrations", null, 1);

                SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();

                String Matricula = etm.getText().toString();
                String Nombre = etn.getText().toString();
                String ApPaterno = etAp.getText().toString();
                String ApMaterno = etAm.getText().toString();
                String Direccion = etd.getText().toString();

                ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();

                    registro.put("Matricula", Matricula);
                    registro.put("Nombre", Nombre);
                    registro.put("ApPaterno", ApPaterno);
                    registro.put("ApMaterno", ApMaterno);
                    registro.put("Direccion", Direccion);
                    bd.insert("Alumno", null, registro);

                    bd.close();
                    etm.setText("");
                    etn.setText("");
                    etAp.setText("");
                    etAm.setText("");
                    etd.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(Alta_Alumno.this, "Datos del usuario guardados", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Hola Pako, bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 

conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 

[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para que 

obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludo

Answer (score 1):

```
SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();
String Matricula = etm.getText().toString();
String Nombre = etn.getText().toString();
String ApPaterno = etAp.getText().toString();
String ApMaterno = etAm.getText().toString();
String Direccion = etd.getText().toS

if(Matricula.getText().toString()=="" || Nombre.getText().toString()=="" || ApPaterno.getText().toString()=="" || ApMaterno.getText().toString()=="" || Direccion.getText().toString()==""){
     ContentValues registro = new ContentV
     registro.put("Matricula", Matricula);
     registro.put("Nombre", Nombre);
     registro.put("ApPaterno", ApPaterno);
     registro.put("ApMaterno", ApMaterno);
     registro.put("Direccion", Direccion);
     bd.insert("Alumno", null, re
     bd.close();
etm.setText("");
etn.setText("");
etAp.setText("");
etAm.setText("");
etd.setText("");
Toast.makeText(Alta_Alumno.this, "Datos del usuario guardados", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}else{

    Toast.makeText(Alta_Alumno.this, "un campo esta vacio, y no se pudo guardar el alumno", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Algo sencillo pero puede funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [**isEmpty()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) para verificar si el `EditText` no tiene contenido, y [trim()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim()) para quitar espacios en los extremos del texto, por ejemplo para validar el `EditText` para almacenar la "matricula":

```
if(etm.getText().toString().trim().isEmtpy()){
   //No tiene valor.
}else{
   //Tiene valor.
}
```

Para asegurar que todos los `EditText` tengan valor puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
 if(etm.getText().toString().trim().isEmtpy() 
                || etn.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()
                || etAp.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()
                || etAm.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()
                || etd.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){

 //falta algún valor.

}else{

 //Se tienen todos los valores.

}
```